# Rolling back changes made by source command

Tags: linux, bash, mysql, colors, grc

I wanted to give the colorization of `MySQL` environment a go, so I searched the internet and found this page:

> [mysql-colorize](https://github.com/unixorn/mysql-colorize.bash)

I followed both of the two directions and it is now working fine. As I checked the results of `SHOW DATABASES;` command I figured that it displays the results in another view, returning back by pressing `Q` button. Because of the fact that I want the results to be shown on the same environment, while containing the command above it (as it is normally done in non-altered MySQL command-line environment), I have decided to remove it and try another one found via the link below:

> [colour-mysql-console](https://github.com/nitso/colour-mysql-console)

But unfortunately when I delete the previously made `~/.bash/` folder, MySQL will only show some errors as below:

> mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
>   sh: /home/caracal/.bash/mysql-colorize/mycat: No such file or directory 
>   7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

I would very much like to order MySQL not to pay attention to the deleted `.bash` folder or its contents and start using the two files brought by `colour-mysql-console` but I don't know at all where to look at and what file to make any desired changes in, to make my desired effects appear. 
Would you please tell me how to fix my problem? Thenk you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried closing the current terminal, and opening another one? So you can have a clean environment?

Comment: Yes, Sorry to forget to mention the result back to the terminal then: `mysql> show databases;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grcat", line 146, in <module>
    split(ll['colours'], ',')
  File "/usr/bin/grcat", line 145, in <lambda>
    ''.join(map(lambda x: get_colour(x), split(colgroup))),
  File "/usr/bin/grcat", line 145, in <lambda>
    ''.join(map(lambda x: get_colour(x), split(colgroup))),
  File "/usr/bin/grcat", line 82, in get_colour
    raise ValueError('Bad colour specified: '+x)
ValueError: Bad colour specified: whit
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
`

Comment: It will start working nicely after entering `pager more`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mysql-colorize` the relevant bits are in `/mysql-colorize.bash`

```
alias mysql="mysql --pager=$(dirname $BASH_SOURCE)/mycat"
```

So to disable it, in the current shell, you would do

```
unalias mysql
```

Comment: Then the same errors occure, and I will have to run the source command again to make it work again: mysql> show databases;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grcat", line 146, in <module>
    split(ll['colours'], ',')
  File "/usr/bin/grcat", line 145, in <lambda>
    ''.join(map(lambda x: get_colour(x), split(colgroup))),
  File "/usr/bin/grcat", line 145, in <lambda>
    ''.join(map(lambda x: get_colour(x), split(colgroup))),
  File "/usr/bin/grcat", line 82, in get_colour
    raise ValueError('Bad colour specified: '+x)
ValueError: Bad colour specified: whit

Comment: And : `bash: unalias: mysql: not found`, so what I did was : `unalias -a`

Comment: Yes, but the `unalias -a` would not solve my problem except that it gave me the idea of creating a file, put `#!/usr/bin/mysql` as the shebang for it and executing it: `source ./file_name`. Now mysql runs without any errors, displaying the returned data in its default manner. Thank you very much for your idea which helped me solve the problem.